# How I can save checkpoint every epoch and load an random saved checkpoint to continue training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Can you help me on my code to : save the model (architecture and weights) every epoch, and how I can continue to training my model from the 5th checkpoint like training epoch from 1 to 25 without making checkpoints(5th model I have saved).

```
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), input_shape = (30, 30, 3), data_format="channels_last", activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08, decay = 0.0)
classifier.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy', precision, recall, fmeasure])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip = True,
                                   rotation_range = 180)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (30, 30),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

validation_set = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/validation_set',
                                                        target_size = (30, 30),
                                                        batch_size = 32,
                                                        class_mode = 'binary')

history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                                   steps_per_epoch = 208170,
                                   epochs = 15,
                                   validation_data = validation_set,
                                   validation_steps = 89140)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you want to save your model and weights after every epoch and then at a later stage, load the model and weights saved after the fifth epoch.

You can use the SaveModel format in TensorFlow in general like this:

```
classifier.save()
```

This will save the architecture, weights, info regarding the optimizer and the configurations you set up in `compile()`

Since you're using fit_generator, you can just use `ModelCheckpoint()` to save your models like this:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(path_to_save_to, save_freq = 'epoch', 
                             save_weights_only = False)

history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                                   steps_per_epoch = 208170,
                                   epochs = 15,
                                   validation_data = validation_set,
                                   validation_steps = 89140,
                                    callbacks = [checkpoint])
```

You can format the path so that it will save the model with epoch/loss details like this `path_name + '-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5'`

To load the fifth checkpoint, do this:

```
from keras.models import load_model
classifier = load_model(path_to_fifth_checkpoint)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how I can continue the training from the 5th model ?

Comment: Once you've provided the path to  ````load_model()```` and loaded the model, ````classifier```` will have the weights and other settings which were associated with the model saved after the fifth epoch.

Comment: Thanks, to continue training from this 5th epoch model, I execute only the code from classifier.compile() to the end ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by that. Once you've loaded the model using the path for the model saved after the fifth epoch, when you start your training, it will be as if you're resuming training after the 5th epoch.